# Find eigenvalues & eigenspaces $Tv=\lambda v \Rightarrow a_1(\lambda - 1)w_1 + a_2(\lambda - 1)w_2 + \sum_{i = 3}^{n}a_i(\lambda + 1)w_i = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I got a formula for $T$ and $v$ base on an orthonormal base $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_n\}$

Therefore, for $Tv=\lambda v$ we get:

$$
\lambda (\sum_i^n a_iw_i) = a_1w_1 + a_1w_2 - \sum_{i=3}^na_i(\lambda + 1)w_i
$$

Getting:

$$
a_1(\lambda - 1)w_1 + a_2(\lambda - 1)w_2 + \sum_{i = 3}^{n}a_i(\lambda + 1)w_i = 0
$$

### NOW THE PROBLEM

From here, the solution says that:

$$
\lambda = 1,-1
$$

Namely, those are the eigenvalues.

And for the eigenspaces for those $\lambda$'s, the solution gets: 
$$
V_{-1} = \{w_3,w_4,...,w_n\}, V_1 = \{w_1,w_2\}
$$

And i dont understand how they got to those eigenvalues and those eigenspaces.

maybe somehow the polynom represent the charactaristic polynom but i dont understand.

How, for example, $\lambda = 1$ gets this polynom to $0$, as an eigenvalue should do.

Help.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the expression reduce to if you set $a_i=0$ for $i\ge3$? Equivalently, what does it look like when $\lambda=-1$?

Comment: How can you do that, you dont know the values of $a_i$ and how can you just do $\lambda = -1$?

Comment: Why can’t you? The goal, after all, is to solve this equation for the unknowns $a_i$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: I dont understand -_-, those are coefficients that you dont knw there values, how can you just say some of them equal $0$, sorry i just dont understand.

Comment: As I already said, your task is to find values for those coefficients for which the equation is satisfied. One way to do that is to pick specific values for some of them and see what that forces the others to be.